# Trying to insert a Json string into an oracle table through c++ code

Tags: c++, json, oracle

I am using TO_CLOB to convert from string to CLOB type. I am writing into the oracle table using a buffer with a default size of 5000 bytes. Problem : When I'm trying to write a Json string with size more than 4000 bytes, code crashes. 
Using the following insert statement :

```
" INSERT INTO STC_DATASET_ID ("
                        " MD5_BASE64, "
                        " **JSON_STR**,"
                        " CREATE_DATE )"
                        " VALUES ( "
                        " :dataset_uid<char[255]>,"
                        " **TO_CLOB(:uid_json_str<char[4000]>)**,"
                        " :current_timestamp<char[255]>)"
```

uid_json_str is passed as an argument to the function.

Comment: Have you tried the Update statement after Insert statement just for the Json field?

Comment: Yes.. I was able to solve the problem by using otl_lob_stream of the otl library